# Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server : SQL Server Network Interfaces: Error Locating Server/Instance Specified [xFFFFFFFF]

Tags: sql, sql-server, windows-server-2012, sql-server-express

Estoy intentando automatizar el Back Up de una base de datos que corre en SQL Server 2014 Express.

Para esto copie un Store Procedure de la página de soporte de Microsoft, este funciona dado que lo corrí desde el Sql Server Management Studio y genera sin inconvenientes el archivo .bak que necesito.

Cuando lo quiero correr mediante un archivo .bat que tiene el siguiente código:

```
sqlcmd -U USUARIO -P P -S .\SQLEXPRESS -Q "EXEC sp_BackupDatabases  @backupLocation ='C:\SQLBackups\', @databaseName=’EntradasLegales’,@BackupType=’F’" -o C:\SQLBackups\LogBK.txt
```

También probé el siguiente:

```
sqlcmd -S .\SQLEXPRESS -U ENT_LEG_USA -P EntL3gpr0d -Q "EXEC sp_BackupDatabases  @backupLocation ='C:\SQLBackups\', @databaseName=’EntradasLegales’,@BackupType=’F’" -o C:\SQLBackups\LogBK.txt
```

El script debe se ejecuta de manera local en el servidor (Windows Server 2012). Dentro del Log se puede observar lo siguiente:

> Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server : SQL Server
>   Network Interfaces: Error Locating Server/Instance Specified
>   [xFFFFFFFF]. . Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server
>   : Login timeout expired. Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 11 for
>   SQL Server : A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred
>   while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or
>   not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is
>   configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL
>   Server Books Online..

¿De que forma debo corregir el script para que este se ejecute sin problemas?

Answer (score 1):

**Server is not found or not accessible.**. Creo que esta es la clave, corrige 
    -S .\SQLEXPRESS

por

```
-S <COMPUTERNAME>\SQLEXPRESS
```

Para asegurar, teniendo en cuenta que lo quieres ejecutar en local (Si lo ejecutas desde una maquina diferente a donde esta la máquina utiliza la IP, asegúrate que tienes el puerto de escucha abierto) ejecuta en el management studio:

```
select @@servername + '\' + @@servicename
```

Y usa el resultado para el parámetro -S

Otra posible causa del problema es que este escuchando en otro puerto diferente, el por defecto es el 1433, si no esta escuchando en este puerto utiliza esta sintaxis para hacer la conexión contra el puerto correcto:

```
sqlcmd -S 127.0.0.1\SQLEXPRESS,1433
```

Espero que te sirva de ayuda. Un saludo.

Comment: De hecho, la clave del mensaje esta al comienzo. `A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection`

Answer (score 0):

La solución a esto es asegurarse de habilitar el protocolo TCP/IP. Esto es diferente a habilitar las conexiones de red en las propiedades del servidor.

Para esto muestro un ejemplo sobre MSSQL 2012, pero lo acabo de probar en  MSSQL 2017 Developer (full) y funciona exactamente igual (y falla exactamente igual cuando está deshabilitado).

1. Abrir *Sql Server configuration manager* en el menú Inicio. Suele estar bajo *SQL Server Tools*.
2. Buscar SQL Server network configuration (o ir dentro de tu instancia nombrada si la creaste y buscar allí network configuration) y habilitar TCP/IP.
3. **MUY IMPORTANTE**: Reiniciar el servicio de tu instancia para que tome los cambios.

[image]